# Structure Nav, Non-Structure Listing Items, & MSM

Tags: structure, navigation

I have a site that uses structure, and has a structure navigation.

- On the homepage, it shows all my top level nav items, which is
  correct.
- On my /news-and-events/news page, which is a structure page
  that draws from the news-and-events.group/news template, it shows the
  top level pages and the news and events sub-pages in the nav, which
  is correct.
- On /news-and-events/news/{url_title}, the nav shows only
  the top level items again, which is incorrect.

The individual news pages run off the same template as /news-and-events/news, just checks segment_3, and pull in content from a separate site within MSM, so they can't be a structure listing.  I need a way to get these individual news pages to show the same nav as the news listing page, either through manipulating the structure nav tag or tricking it into thinking I'm still on the news page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Post your {exp:structure:nav} code

Comment: It is, at the moment, literally just that. {exp:structure:nav} I haven't found any parameters that help with this use case.

Answer (score 1):

This code tells Structure Nav to always start at root and to show 2 levels of the tree all the time:

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from="/" max_depth="2"}
```

Structure Nav Docs:
http://www.buildwithstructure.com/tags/navigation/

Comment: Tried this and it did not work.

Comment: What does {exp:structure:nav start_from="/{segment_1}/{segment_2}" max_depth="2"} do?

Answer (score 0):

```
{exp:structure:nav start_from='/' max_depth="2" show_depth="2"}
```

Does adding show_depth help?